# TIA Bloomberg Historical Request With Overrides Python

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am trying to do a historical data pull with overrides but I keep getting an error for using too many arguments.

```
I have the following:

import pandas as pd
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm

mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()

ticker = 'AAPL US EQUITY'

sids = mgr[ticker]

info_df = (sides.get_historical(
           ['BEST_SALES','BEST_OPP', 'BEST_EBITDA', 'BEST_EBIT'],
           start_date = "1/1/2000",
           end_date = "6/30/2016",
           "DAILY",
           "BE997=1GY")
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: get_historical() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)
```

If I remove `"DAILY"` it doesn't like the periodicity.  If I include the periodicity it doesn't seem to take the override.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import pandas as pd
import tia.bbg.datamgr as dm

mgr = dm.BbgDataManager()

ticker = 'AAPL US EQUITY'

sids = mgr[ticker]

info_df = sids.get_historical(
       ['BEST_SALES','BEST_OPP', 'BEST_EBITDA', 'BEST_EBIT'],
       start="1/1/2000",
       end="6/30/2016",
       period="DAILY",
       BE997="1GY")
```